# Neverwinter Nights 2 multiple hakpack problem

Tags: neverwinter-nights-2

I've been playing around with hakpacks for NWN 2 recently. I first downloaded and installed Kaedrin's PrC pack, and it worked great. Yippy skippy. But when I downloaded and installed the Races of Faerun hakpack, the two hakpacks conflicted, because you have to use the dialogue.tlk from both of them to get them to work, but they won't play nicely because they have the same file name and need to be in the same directory. Does anyone know how to have both hakpacks installed AND working?

Answer (score 2):

After a whole hell of a lot of searching, I found the answer inside of the readme for this combined hak: http://nwvault.ign.com/View.php?view=NWN2HakpaksCombined.Detail&id=58

Answer (score 1):

You can combine hakpaks manually too

http://nwvault.ign.com/?dir=resources/tutorials/&content=CombiningHakPaks

Comment: Can you add the relevant details from the link, please?  Saves people a click.